# How to support static and class methods when passing positional arguments from a decorator?

Tags: python-2.7, parameter-passing, decorator, static-methods, python-decorators

I want to write a decorator that passes an additional positional argument at first position, but after `self` or `cls`, to the wrapped function.

```
def handle_route(self, url, headers):
    pass

@require_login
def handle_route(self, user, url, headers):
    pass
```

Since there are staticmethods, classmethods and normal methods, how do I know at what position to pass the additional argument?

```
import functools

def require_login(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        user = obtain_user(kwargs.get('headers', {}))
        return function(user, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This example only words for staticmethods. In the other cases, user gets passed as `self` or `cls` argument causing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wish to do is best done using a decorator *class*, not a decorator *function*. You can then implement the full [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), which is otherwise inherited from the function.

Specifically, you need to create a `__get__` method for your object. You can then defer the resolution of class-/static-/regular-method to the wrapped method.

```
class RequireLogin(object):
  def __init__(self, wrapee):
    self.wrapee = wrapee
    self.user = 'foo' # changeme

  def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
      return self.wrapee.__get__(instance, owner)(self.user, *args, **kwargs)
      #                  ^ use class/static/regular method's __get__
    return wrapped
```